# Select a row only if a field from previous row is less from a field in the active row

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I would like to know if its possible to create a query which will select a row only if a field in the previous row has a value smaller then the value in the actual row.

If you check this screenshot:

[image]

The ID which equals 7 will not be selected because the row after it has value which is less then the actual value. So I would like to know if there is a LINQ to Entities command which will help me to exclude the rows such as row with id of 7 from the select results.

Comment: This seems like an usual data model.  Maybe if you explain the higher level problem, there might be a better model for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ids are guaranteed to be consecutive, you can join the table to itself by id onto id -1

```
var q = from x in test
        join y in test on x.ID equals y.ID - 1
        where y.StopOrder >= y.ID
        select x;
```

You'd have to think about boundary conditions, you might want the equivalent of a left join.

If your ids are not consecutive, you can do something like:

```
var q = from x in test
        from y in test 
        where y.ID > x.ID
        group y by x into g
        where g.Min().ID <= g.Min().StopOrder
        select g.Key;
```

For this to work you need to define IComparable on the table type. In my test I used:

```
struct X: IComparable<X> {
    public int ID;
    public int StopOrder;
    public int CompareTo (X other) {
        return ID.CompareTo(other.ID);
    }
}
```

This will still never return the last row.

If you're using SQL2012 or higher and want to drop down to SQL, you can use the `lead` function. This will only scan the table once (assuming an index on ID):

```sql
with x as (
  select
    t.ID,
    t.StopOrder,
    lead(id, 1) over (order by id) as NextID,
    lead(StopOrder, 1) over (order by id) as NextStopOrder
  from
    test t
) select
  x.ID,
  x.StopOrder
from
  x
where
  x.NextId <= x.NextStopOrder;
```

Also, if you want the last row, you can just add `or x.NextID is null` to the end

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a53f6/4)

Comment: @Silvermind it doesn't work if there's a gap between ids. If it was me, I'd probably drop down to using `row_number()` in sql rather than trying to shoehorn it into linq in that case.

Comment: @Laurence You're right, I focus to much on the code, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As SQL is declarative, the DBMS can make plenty of decisions about how it retrieves the result, and this may well involve multithreading.

When this occurs, there is no guarantee about the order in which the threads will complete, and therefore, the order in which the results will be returned - **even** if you have a primary key defined. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx) is a good explanation of what goes on there.

Therefore, I'd recommend getting the consecutive numbering sorted by the database, but ensuring that the results are then ordered once they're back from the database, and then carrying out the filtering on the ordered result set in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is not too big to pull all records, it might be easier to write an extension method that does the filtering (sorry, I didn't quite understand the condition you meant):

```
public static class MyTypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<MyType> FilterOnStopOrder(this IEnumerable<MyType> source)
    {
        MyType previous = null;
        foreach (var item in source.OrderBy(s => s.ID))
        {
            // or whatever condition... 
            if (previous != null && previous.StopOrder < item.StopOrder)
            {
                yield return item;
            }

            previous = item;
        }
    }
}
```